# Add extra btn-group onclick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

As you can see, I have a button group. I'm trying to extend this functionality in such a way that when i click on any of the three buttons (left, middle or right), corresponding buttons (left-sub, middle-sub or right-sub) appears respectively as and when clicked:

```
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left" btn-checkbox>Left</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.left-sub" btn-checkbox>Left-Sub</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle" btn-checkbox>Middle</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.middle-sub" btn-checkbox>Middle-Sub</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox>Right</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right-sub" btn-checkbox>Right-Sub</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right-sub-2" btn-checkbox>Right-Sub-2</label>
    </div>
```

I'm new to angularJS and can't seem to figure out how to go about this. Even if i  get a sample code to work on, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you written something in code?

Comment: Did you try any of the built in directives such as ngShow/Hide or ngIf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the names of your ng-model, as they aren't legal with `-` in the key names.

Then you can just use ngIf:

```
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox>Right</label>
    <!--This one displays if checkModel.right is true (i.e., if the Right button is checked)-->
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.rightSub" btn-checkbox ng-if="checkModel.right">Right-Sub</label>
    <!--This one displays if checkModel.rightSub is true (i.e., if the Right-Sub button is checked)-->
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.rightSub2" btn-checkbox ng-if="checkModel.rightSub">Right-Sub-2</label>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Let me play around and get back to you with further queries :) Thank You so much

Comment: It works like a charm. I'm sorry i couldn't write to you sooner. I got busy with another module. Thank You so much :)

Comment: No prob, just checking in.  Best of luck with it!

Comment: What should i do if i want to keep the rightSub and rightSub2 open permanently after it is clicked?

Comment: You could disable the buttons once they are clicked the first time. So, for example: if you wanted to make sure that once clicked, checkModel.right stays true you would add: ng-disabled="checkModel.right".  That would mean it couldn't be set it to false, therefore rightSub would stay visible.  Does that help?

Comment: Am i doing it wrong? It disabled the rightSub completly! Here's the code: <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="checkModel.rightSub" btn-checkbox ng-if="checkModel.right" ng-disabled="checkModel.right">Right-Sub</label>

Comment: Yup, it's wrong.  You want to add the ng-disabled to the checkModel.right button: `<label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox ng-disabled="checkModel.right">Right</label>`  this way once it's set to true, it will become disabled.

Comment: Even better, you can do: `<label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="checkModel.right" btn-checkbox ng-disabled="checkModel.right && checkModel.rightSub">Right</label>`.  Then it will only be disabled if it's true AND the rightSub is true.  This way, if you want to set right to false again, you just have to back out of rightSub.

Comment: This worked. Thank you once again. Can't thank you enough :) :) :)